# Making a DNS request using Java and timing the response

Tags: java, dns, applet, response-time

Could some one show me how I can make a DNS request to a particular DNS server and get the response as well as the response time?

I intend to use this in an signed applet. Is this allowed in an applet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard Java API's you can use is:

[java.net.InetAddress](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html)

Or the more advanced JNDI lookup API:

[DNS Service Provider for the Java Naming Directory Interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jndi/jndi-dns.html)

Both above Java API's will work in an signed applet if the applet is granted the required policy rights (java.net.SocketPermission for example). But when the applet is used on a web page, the user will first be shown a dialog that asks for permission to run. To measure performance of these API calls, one can of course use a simple call to [java.lang.Systen.currentTimeMillis()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis())

*I do not recommend using [dnsjava.org](http://www.dnsjava.org/), it used to be popular, but the project has not been updated since 2004.*

Answer (score 0):

Just call one of the InetAddress methods, or else have a look at JNDI with the DNS provider.

Answer (score -2):

You need a Java implementation of DNS, such as [dnsjava](http://www.dnsjava.org/) (see [examples.html](http://www.dnsjava.org/dnsjava-current/examples.html)). It's certainly not possible to use this in an applet, as it violates the networking restrictions.

Comment: No you don't. You dont need anything outside the java API.